# Multiprocessing items in a list - Python, To avoid clashes would usage of queue be required?

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I have a list of 18k ids and want to perform 3 functions i.e

1. fetch_data_from_db(),
2. data_clean(),
3. push_data_back_to_db()

For each of the 18k records, I want to perform 1,2 in sequence and dump the output to files. 3. can be kicked off at a later stage.

To make it complete faster, I am trying to multiprocess by writing a wrapper function around (1,2) using pool library.

```
from multiprocessing import pool
import time
list_of_18k = [1,2,3,4,5....]

def func(id):
   fetch_data_from_db(id)
   data_clean(id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = pool.Pool()
  res = p.map(func, list_of_18k)

  p.close()
  p.join()
```

Question is, if we simply run it this way, will it automatically distribute the list of 18k ids to each of the processes(cores) and no process will read the list item twice?? or is it necessary to use locks before list_of_18k = [] or add some queue / pipe??

Comment: map does not repeat the item from the list

Comment: Are you aware that your `func()` is not taking any argument? Where do you get `id` from? Is `id` an item of the list?

Comment: So take out multiprocessing and pools from this code. How does 'id' currently get passed to func()? Should that be a param of the function? How are you currently processing the list? Those seem to be the bigger issues. Because as it stands, the base code doesn't work, so tacking on pooling just for the sake of "make it faster" isn't going to do very much.

Comment: @alec_djinn, ...  yes, it was just a representational code i put up there. for the sake of understanding the need of lock / queue needs to be implemented or not.. I have corrected it.. it was not the complete code anyway.. i havent put up the functions content, definations all that if you noticed, just an example to ask the question

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim yes, it was just a representational code i put up there. for the sake of understanding the need of lock / queue needs to be implemented or not.. I have corrected it.. it was not the complete code anyway.. i havent put up the functions content, definations all that if you noticed, just an example to ask the question

Comment: @Viv You have to post a more realistic code, otherwise it hard to guess. It is not clear what the database is, that is found a mental to understand if you can parallelizzi or not your functions. Please give a proper working example to work with.